# racket: keep updating list with new result

Tags: scheme, racket

lets say i have 2 lists.

```
(define wholelist '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20))
(define firstlist '(1 3 4 6 7 8 10 13 15 18))

(define (removelist list1 list2)
        (remove* list1 list2))

(removelist firstlist wholelist)

> '(2 5 9 11 12 14 16 17 19 20)
```

it works perfectly fine. But what i want to do is, lets say i want to remove another list from wholelist, but this time, the wholelist will be the result of the above code.

```
(defind secondlist '(2 3 5 6 7 10 13 16 17 18 19 20))

(removelist secondlist wholelist)

> '(1 4 8 9 11 12 14 15)       --> i want this result as '(9 11 12 14)
```

so i want the wholelist is keep updating so i can use it for further computation.
is there any way to change wholelist value as my result from 1st computation without defining a new list?

thank you so much!

Comment: Can scheme/raket have mutables? Or you could try re-assigning the reference, unless the reference is immutable itself, but that would still allocate a new list to the heap unless you played with wholelist at a lower level somehow. I know a little common lisp and scala, and a bit about functional programming, so I can understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want is

```
> (removelist secondlist (removelist firstlist wholelist))
'(9 11 12 14)
```

If you need to split that into 2 steps, you need to bind the intermediary result of `(removelist firstlist wholelist)` with `define`, `let` or `set!` depending on the context:

1. do you want to mutate the original binding - use `set!` (not recommended)
2. if you can introduce a new, temporary binding (possible with the same name, shadowing the original) - use `define` or `let`.

Example of the latter:

```
> (let ((wholelist (removelist firstlist wholelist))) 
    (removelist secondlist wholelist))
'(9 11 12 14)
```